# How to sort Multiple Selection Lookup Cells in list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I have a list with a lookup column that allows users to select multiple items by adding them to the selection when they edit the item. I'd like to be able to have the list alphabetize the selections after they are saved.

So in one row, if the selections made in the order B;D;A, I want it to reorder to A;B;D.  I can't seem to find a setting that will do this.

Comment: I found a workaround.  It's a short list so I went to datasheet view and for each cell in the column, opened the dropdown and hit okay.  This reordered them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create either some client-side code (JavaScript) or a workflow that will handle that logic as it isn't something you can do through column set up alone.